# Dgrid Pagging not retrieving data back to server

Tags: dojo, dgrid

I am trying to use Dojo's dGrid as a replacement for jqGrid because it cannot do multiple-line row data. The dgrid site has a sample pagination that retrieves data once and does the pagination multiple times. I am concern with this because it may cause performance problem if the data is already too large. I was wondering if dGrid has an option to do pagging while requesting data for each pagination.

The source example in the dojo site.

```
http://dojofoundation.org/packages/dgrid/tutorials/grids_and_stores/demo/Pagination.html
```

I checked the option for Pagination and there seems to be no logic to change the behavior of the store.

```
https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/wiki/Pagination
```

Also, for the store data query. Is the data only filtered by client based.

Edited After answer:

I noticed that the following question also partially answer this question. Adding for future reference. -nap
[Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838500/paging-is-not-working-using-jsonrest-with-enhancedgrid?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dojo has a standard [Store API](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/intro_dojo_store/) which all data-driven components use, including dgrid. The dgrid demo uses a basic Memory store which is not appropriate for a production site. You would implement and use a [JsonRest](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/store/JsonRest.html) or similar store for your server instead of a Memory store to use with your production site.

Comment: The answer is ok but it would be better if you have examples on this.